# Amazon Lex custom slot type issue using EXPANDED VALUES

Tags: amazon-lex

Our team has been developing a chatbot with Amazon Lex for around 3 months now and we need a slot type that will accept ANY last name.  The built-in AMAZON.US_LASTNAME slot type appears to be limiting and we need every name to be accepted the first time they are entered.

We created and trained a last_name custom slot type with a significant enumerationValues list and set the slot resolution to EXPANDED VALUES to theoretically accept any value (I believe that’s how it works but happy to hear otherwise).  Our last_name slot type is not accepting any last name that is not in our enumerationValues list, so it appears the EXPANDED VALUES resolution is not working as I understand it should be.

Any advice on how to create a custom slot that will accept any last name?

Comment: are you extracting last name from the full name or are you prompting it separately ?

Comment: prompting separately.  I spoke with lex tech support before posting this and they said to go down the custom slot route, train with up to 10,000 values and make sure expanded values is the resolution type which I did.  The problem is it still doesn't consistently catch all possible last names.  They recommended I capture the lex rejections, save locally and manually fire off the next slot.  Doing this causes other issues for us but we'll do it if we have to.  i was hoping there was better solution out there.

Comment: If you want to accept absolutely anything for that slot, have you considered just taking whatever the user input and force that into the last_name slot yourself? That works for me quite well, and I created a custom slotType called "PlaceHolder" for any slot I use like that.

Comment: Thanks Jay.  We've implemented a workaround that seems pretty flexible as well.  If we find inconsistencies in a built in slot or need a slot to accept any value we create a customer slot and if that fails to accept a value we trap the response, send back the slot name to lex (which is built into the custom slot type values), and save the actual value ourselves.  Then if a subsequent slot prompt uses the results of a previous answer we look for the slot name in the prompt in the UI and replace it with our saved value before the prompt is displayed/read.  So far so  good.